# Can I use NAudio to record audio in a Blazor app?

Tags: naudio, blazor

In a dotnetcore 3.0 Blazor app I want to be able to record audio using NAudio, instead of implementing an HTML5 control in Javascript. Does NAudio support this?

I have already tried the sample code below. I am getting a 0 byte wave file written to my Desktop.

```
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
@using System
@using System.IO
@using NAudio.Wave

<button @ref="recordButton" @onclick="Record">Record</button>
<button @ref="stopRecording" @onclick="StopRecording">Stop</button>

@code {

    ElementReference recordButton;
    ElementReference stopRecording;

    WaveInEvent waveIn;

    public void Record()
    {        
        var outputFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "NAudio");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(outputFolder);
        var outputFilePath = Path.Combine(outputFolder, "recorded.wav");

        waveIn = new WaveInEvent();

        WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(outputFilePath, waveIn.WaveFormat);
        waveIn.StartRecording();

        waveIn.DataAvailable += (s, a) =>
        {
            writer.Write(a.Buffer, 0, a.BytesRecorded);
        };

    }

    public void StopRecording()
    {
        waveIn.StopRecording();
    }

}
```

Comment: You didn't state Client (Wasm) or Server side Blazor.

Comment: But in either case, all I/O has to go through JavaScript. So the answer will be No.

Answer (score 0):

We had to use Javascript to access the user's microphone.

Comment: Could you provide more information;
Are there any articles on the solution? Is there some documentation you followed? The code that helped you?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).